# Page loads an image that doesn't exist in my folder

Tags: python, css, django, image

I am working on a web app. I found a free template to use for my home page and I copied the navbar from the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="header__inner">
                <div class="header__logo"><a href=""><img src="{% static 'home/img/logo.png' %}" alt="Logo" /></a></div>
                <div class="header__menu">

                    <!-- onepage-nav -->
                    <nav class="onepage-nav">
                        <!-- onepage-menu -->
                        <ul class="onepage-menu">
                            <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Discover</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Events</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="">About</a>
                        </ul><!-- onepage-menu -->

                        <div class="navbar-toggle"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
                    </nav><!-- End / onepage-nav -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying to change the image. I have another project that uses the free template in the same folder with the project I'm working on, but my current project doesn't even have any folders in static directory. So there's no images, CSS, JS or styling at all in my current project. I can't find what's the problem with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you have a picture called 'logo.png' somewhere?

Comment: did you collect static files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem and can't find a solution after making all the necessary checks, **clean your browser cache**. In my case I used the same code with another project and when I run my new project, it kept showing the old image even though my image folder was empty. So the browser cached the image from the other project for my localhost address.
Might look like something insignificant, but sometimes it takes time unnecessarily.